# Detecting hypervisors in Puppet

Tags: virtualization, puppet

Puppet provides a fact `vitual` which is supposed to show what virtualization method a system is using. We use Redhat 7 and 8 for guest operating systems. We have a lot of `physical` systems, and also use RedHat Virtualization, KVM, and Linode. The documentation for `virt-what` says it can detect `rhev`, but that seems to only detect the old version, not newer versions which are just reported as `kvm`. Similarly, Linodes are also reported as `kvm`.

One of the biggest issues is that each machine should have different VM guest tools/services installed based on the hypervisor in use (for example, it seems that Linodes should not have guest tools at all). Is there a better way to figure out what the actual hypervisor is?

Comment: rhev is kvm: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/4.4/html-single/product_guide/index, table 1.1, hosts. Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571395/differences-between-rhv-and-kvm

Comment: but maybe you could define rhev if specific files exist on the file system of the host, like, for instance, the ovirt-* commands. I don't know how to do this in puppet though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for virt-what to print both `rhev` (or `ovirt`)  and `kvm`. The former from product or manufacturer data, and the latter probably from CPUID.

factor also has its own implementations of guessing, plus virt-what. This plus the unreliability of guessing hypervisor in general means getting `rhev` back is not guaranteed.

In practice, check what the fact returns on all hypervisors and hosting providers you use.

And know what to expect on various platforms.  `hyperv` or Azure means Hyper-V.  `vmware` is well, VMware.  `rhev`, `ovirt`, `kvm` are Linux KVM, and is in use in the cloud at Linode, AWS, Google, among others, or on premise Linux.  `bhyve` is FreeBSD. `vmm` is OpenBSD. POWER and IBM Z have hypervisors.  Some of these are more popular than others, but all can run RHEL guests.